# Set text and image on Splash screen: invalid drawable tag RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I follow the code on the link below,

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67821/splash-screen-with-text

Below is my code,

splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="My test"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but I get error

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag RelativeLayout
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1124)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
    ... 29 more
  Force finishing activity 1 myapp.SplashActivity
```

OS: Lollipop, Xamarin Android

**Update**

Splash activity

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/MySplashTheme")]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(ManifestActivity)));

        Finish();
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MySplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67821/splash-screen-with-text

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31091/splash-screen-using-a-layout

[Xamarin : Splash screen using a Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987195/xamarin-splash-screen-using-a-layout)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119638/splash-screen-using-android-windowbackground-does-goes-behind-statusbar

Comment: It's supposed to be an Android Layout file known as AXML not XML, perhaps you've gotten it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I executed your layout and is working properly.

Do you have your primary color declared like that in the colors.xml:

```
<color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
```

Comment: I dont know. Can you share your Splash activity?

Comment: I think you dont need your splash.xml to launch your splash screen. Take a look to this sample to get an idea how it should be implemented: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-splash-screen-for-android-app-in-xamarin/

Comment: do you think using splash.xml is the problem?

Comment: You don't have a reference to the splash.xml in your SplashActivity, I am assuming that splash.xml is not used. You can try to test if windowBackground is working, try to change @drawable/splash to @color/primary and check if the splash activity is launched

Comment: splash.xml is used via  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>

Comment: So that's the problem. You are using a layout as drawable. You need change splash.xml to use it as drawable

Comment: how to change it to activity xml instead of using @drawable/splash?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `android:windowBackground` to set the with background for the activity you should use it with a drawable resource  then set the same as the theme for your activity.

Alternatively , if you want to use the layout.xml the just remove the theme(since its not right now) and just set the

`// set the user interface layout for this activity
    // the layout file is defined in the project res/layout/main_activity.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Also in this case, you will have to intent to the next activity after a delay , while in the previous case windowbackground is visible for the time the activity was loaded and then intent is fired, now the layout is loaded (which is now the backgound) and soon the intent fires hence the some delay is required.